# how to use radio and submit button with tables

Tags: html

I tried to add a reset button and submit button, to a form which includes tables, but they do not work

here's the code:

```html
<forms name="f1">
  <table valign='center'>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td> <input type="text" name="f1"> <br> <br> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="top">
      <td>Age: </td>
      <td> <input type="text" name="f2"> <br> <br> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="top">
      <td>Email:</td>
      <td> <input type="text" name="f3"> <br> <br> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="top">
      <td>News Type:</td>
      <td>
        <select> <br> <br>
          <option> Tech </option>
          <option> Gaming </option>
          <option> Homepage </option>
          <option> Stocks </option>
          <option> Sports </option>
        </select><br><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="top">
      <td>Comments:</td>
      <td> <textarea cols="50" rows="5"> Give Feedback  </textarea><br> <br> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input type="reset" value="reset"></td>
      <td align="right"> <input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</forms>
```

Comment: should be form instead of forms

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: Please change `<forms name="f1"></forms>` to `<form name="f1"></form>`

Comment: I also suggest `<textarea cols="50" rows="5" placeholder="Give Feedback"></textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

Please using Form tag instead of forms, Refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp)

```html
<form name="f1">
  <table valign='center'>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td> <input type="text" name="f1"> <br> <br> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="top">
      <td>Age: </td>
      <td> <input type="text" name="f2"> <br> <br> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="top">
      <td>Email:</td>
      <td> <input type="text" name="f3"> <br> <br> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="top">
      <td>News Type:</td>
      <td>
        <select> <br> <br>
          <option> Tech </option>
          <option> Gaming </option>
          <option> Homepage </option>
          <option> Stocks </option>
          <option> Sports </option>
        </select><br><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="top">
      <td>Comments:</td>
      <td> <textarea cols="50" rows="5"> Give Feedback  </textarea><br> <br> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input type="reset" value="reset"></td>
      <td align="right"> <input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I re-created your example by using Event Handlers with **Javascript (JQuery)**.
If you do not want to use **Javascript** then please feel free to use @Shivasagar example.

*Here is my snippet:*

```js
// Adding event listener on the reset button
$('input[name="reset"]').click(function(event) {
  // Then setting the values of the form to nothing
  $('input[name="name"]').val('');
  $('input[name="age"]').val('');
  $('input[name="email"]').val('');

  $('select[name="newsType"]').val('None');

  $('textarea[name="comments"]').val('');
});

// Prevent submit from submiting
$('input[name="submit"]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Form</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
          crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="f1">
      <table class="table table-responsive">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="name"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Age:</td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="age"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="email"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>News Type:</td>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control" name="newsType">
                <option value="None" style="display: none;" selected> -- select an option -- </option>
                <option value="Tech">Tech</option>
                <option value="Gaming">Gaming</option>
                <option value="Homepage">Homepage</option>
                <option value="Stocks">Stocks</option>
                <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Comments:</td>
            <td><textarea cols="50" rows="5" placeholder="Give Feedback" name="comments"></textarea></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input class="btn btn-light float-left" type="button" value="Reset" name="reset"></td>
            <td><input class="btn btn-light float-right" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```